# Cookies: Does a cookie's time ever get updated? Like... is the expiration a sliding window?

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

Lets say that the cookie has an expiration of 1 day. Does the cookie expire in the middle of a session at the end of that 24 hour period? does the cooke's expiration date slide for every log-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the cookie could expire in the middle of a session at the end of the 24 hour period.But it would affect the user only if you check it at the time.No, cookie expire time will not extend with a login.

Comment: As a follow-up question: Is there a way to set sliding Expiration on a cookie like for authentication cookies?

Comment: Well it depends on your specific langauage whether it has a buit in method/function to extend the expiration.Otherwise you can extend it manually in every login by adding new period on the same key.